# String in a conditional formatting formula in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to format column G if column D has "AI" in the same row using VBA in Excel 2007.

If i do it manually in the conditional formatting editor the formula `=(D1 = "AI")` works correctly.

If i try to add this formula to the Formula1 clause of a FormatConditions.Add method i must put
  `="(D1 = ""AI"")"` or the interpreter complains. But this is copied literally with the doubled double quotes as the condition and the formatting does nothing.

What should I put in Formula1 ?

Antonio

Comment: If you want to format `G` based on `F` why are you using `D1`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
Sub Macro2()

Sheet1.Range("G1").Select
With Sheet1.Range("G:G")
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=F1=""AI"""
    .FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End With
End Sub
```

Also, using VBA to set conditional formatting has always been a bit wonky (for me at least).  The only way I could get it to work was to select G1 and then set the formatting.  I know typically you don't need to select, but in this case it's the only way I could get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula:

=$F$1="AI"

This will result in the below.

[image]

In VBA you could do this:

```
="=$F$1=" + Chr (34) + "AI" + Chr (34) + ")"
```

Chr (34) is `"` (double quote)

Also you could use:

If Range("F1") = "AI" Then Range("G1").Interior.Color = 65535

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in VBA, then why are you using conditional formatting at all? Simply look at the value in G and set the format of F directly in the VBA code.

Comment: Well, I have the idea that if I use Excel's built in features my macros will be  faster than if i use ForEach loops..